# Am I an engineer?

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Recently, an electrical engineer studying traffic light timings was [fined $500 by the state of Oregon](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/oregon-man-fined-for-writing-i-am-an-engineer-temporarily-wins-the-right-to-call-himself-an-engineer) for referring to himself as an engineer.

Given a 2 letter string as input, representing a US state, output:

- `I am not an engineer` if the state is Oregon (`OR`)
- `I am an engineer` if the state is any other US state
- `What is an engineer?` given any other input

Output may not contain any *leading* whitespace, but may contain as much *trailing* whitespace as you wish.

You can assume the input will always be 2 uppercase letters.

Here is a list of all 50 US state abbreviations:

```
AL, AK, AZ, AR, CA, CO, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI, ID, IL, IN, IA, KS, KY, LA, ME,
MD, MA, MI, MN, MS, MO, MT, NE, NV, NH, NJ, NM, NY, NC, ND, OH, OK, OR, PA,
RI, SC, SD, TN, TX, UT, VT, VA, WA, WV, WI, WY
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: Can I have a trailing space in the output?

Comment: @BusinessCat yes, will update spec to say that

Comment: Side note: If you concatenate the whole string together, you get "...OKOR**PARIS**CSDTN..."  ;-)

Comment: Mats Järlström wouldn't be allowed to present himself as an engineer in Texas, either.

Answer (score 17):

## C#, <s>311 309</s> <s>240</s> <s>237</s> <s>222</s> <s>195</s> <s>184</s> 183 bytes

```
s=>s=="OR"?"I am not an engineer":"MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY".Contains(s)?"I am an engineer":"What is an engineer?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BT8JAEIXv@yte9tQmyg8QC9kUkEp3SwCpaDystcFN2q3pLCaG8NvrIh4kkcPLJPPNvJlX0HXd2KbbkbFbLL/IlXWfsaLSRBB7xj52r5UpQE47XyY7W9ySa/3wFU51AB11FA0oini24EOeQNewjYO2KO3W2LJs@Q2XiYpFKiCX8UpJtRazDXLxhLlYYJLiTkBNkxHibLYcQY4hR15@fPUINYa6h9pAeZJNkS0SgYcV8rVXkiLf8F7cWKeNpYDC3xfOz@fv2sHQ3@6Q97vzeJ@NeYP0NsEp2/MLdLulkO2Z96emKnt5a1yZ@v1AB8e8Ydj/n4n0Mouzy2wuf9iBHbpv)

*Saved 2 bytes by adding the space before `an` to `b`*

*<s>-69 (huehue)</s> -72 bytes thanks to TheLethalCoder*

*-15 bytes thanks to TotallyHuman's genius states string*

*-38 bytes cos more string compression*

Ungolfed:

```
public static string a(string s)
{
    var b = " an engineer";
    if (s == "OR")
    {
        return "I am not" + b;
    }
    else
    {
        if ("MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY".Contains(s))
        {
            return "I am" + b;
        }
        else
        {
            return $"What is{b}?";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `..."+b` instead of interpolated strings, change `if..else if...else` to `return s==`"OR"?....:System.Arr...` i.e. use a ternary. Use `u.Contains` instead of `Array.Exists`. I think if you use spaces instead of commas then `.Split()` with no params will work.

Comment: declare b and u in the same line and even though you have to use explicit type string should still save you a byte

Comment: @StefanDelport `u` is an array not string. However, you can save bytes by setting `u` as a string and using `.Contains` on it.

Comment: 240 bytes: `s=>{var b=" an engineer";return s=="OR"?"I am not"+b:"AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY".Contains(s)?"I am"+b:$"What is{b}?";};`. Think I've removed all the relevant whitespace. (Untested)

Comment: 237: `s=>s=="OR"?"I am not an engineer":"AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY".Contains(s)?"I am an engineer":"What is an engineer?";` implicit return with all strings fully hardcoded, untested but should work. Mmm probably should have made my own solution... Oh well have this for free :P

Comment: An anonymous user suggested saving a byte by dropping the `O` from `ORIA`.

Comment: `PAR` and `RIA` can be joined to save 2 bytes.

Comment: The input "" responds "I am an engineer." instead of "What is an engineer?".

Comment: I think `COHINCALAKSCTNVARIAZ MNMOKY WVTX MSDE MIL WID FL GA ME MA NJ NY NH PA WA WY NE MD MT ND UT` works an saves 2 bytes.

Comment: You can golf this by defining " an engineer" as a separate variable to save some bytes.

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), 182 bytes

```js
s=>['I am'+(x=' an engineer'),`What is${x}?`,'I am not'+x][s=='OR'?2:'MNNMLATNAKALARAZCACOCTDEFLGAHIIAIDILINKSKYMAMDMEMIMOMSMTNCNDNENHNJNVNYOHOKPARISCSDTXUTVAVTWAWIWVWY'.search(s)&1]
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

s=>['I am'+(x=' an engineer'),`What is${x}?`,'I am not'+x][s=='OR'?2:'MNNMLATNAKALARAZCACOCTDEFLGAHIIAIDILINKSKYMAMDMEMIMOMSMTNCNDNENHNJNVNYOHOKPARISCSDTXUTVAVTWAWIWVWY'.search(s)&1]

console.log(f("OR"))
console.log(f("NY"))
console.log(f("TX"))
console.log(f("YO"))
```

Comment: Fails for e.g. `LA` :/

Comment: @Christoph Should be OK now. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Thought it was missing OR for moment - silly!

Comment: Use https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124164/76323 to optimize

Answer (score 8):

## C, <s>215</s> <s>208</s> 190 bytes

<sup>-7 thanks to Cool Guy</sup>

```
#define z" an engineer"
#define f(s)!strcmp(s,"OR")?"I am not"z:strstr("MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY",s)?"I am"z:"What is"z"?"
```

Used @totallyhuman's "genus string".

How it works:

- `"string"z` automatically concatenates `"string"` with `z` (`" an engineer"`). Yes, C does that.
- `!strcmp(s,"OR")` compares the string against "OR".
- `?"I am not"z` returns "I am not an engineer" if true. Otherwise...
- `:strstr(...,s)` checks if @totallyhuman's genius string contains the provided string.
- `?"I am"z` returns "I am an engineer" if so, and...
- `:"What is"z"?")` returns "What is an engineer?" otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xT8MwFIR3fsXxWJyqDKx0qKykUNPYQWloSCsGy6RthpgqDksQv928gUp3w73vSXfu/uRcjHef7bHzLSaC9Wj9iUM70M31fhQhuQ3j4PqLCHMqSkqWpGB7@K@RpkdGLEFamVTmEnqbVkabndw0qOUer7LEU45nCbNWGdJis82gV9AZm9@rd5gVzAtMA8OkWKNUEm8V6h1b5agbmof/Ui6k@mxHdIEmWlLsbeeFZe7OdpjNwuLn8j0GwasPDx9JsviNsSj/AA)

Comment: 206 bytes: `#define z " an engineer"
f(char*s){!strcmp(s,"OR")?puts("I am not"z):strstr("MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY",s)?puts("I am"z):puts("What is"z);}`

Comment: @CoolGuy That won't work for "What is an engineer?" But I got it to work in 209 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: You can return the string instead of printing it

Comment: @l4m2 Did something similar.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>228</s> 168 bytes

```python
lambda s:('What is%s?','I am'+' not'*(s=='OR')+'%s')[s in'MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY']%' an engineer'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBT4MwHIbxs3yK90L@rTMePC4hpoHpcNAahkM2jamxkyZb11DI4qdHDr/T8/i/obu4h@mYfEwnff7@0QhLRk2nB9gQh0e6oxz6TAuCuwx0y0KSkKqILygOxA8B1lGZy1QUAuU2rWUpd2LTohF7vIoKTwWeBeQ6z5CqzTZDuUKZzea9fodcQb5AtpBzUWuoKhd4q9HsZnmBpqXPmKAdjPu1zpiepmtnTwZ1P5pldON76wZ2ZL2@flnnx4Hx@9F70zPO@SSKSFWRUv8)

Comment: The state encoding is hilarious.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>192</s> <s>186</s> <s>182</s> <s>178</s> 176 bytes

Could probably compress the state string more.

```python
lambda s,e=' an engineer':'I am'+' not'*(s=='OR')+e if s in'MINCALAZ SCT FL GA WIAKSD ME MD MA MNMS MOKY MTNE NVTX NH NJ NY ND COHIDE OR PARIL UT VA WA WV WY'else'What is%s?'%e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZdJRa4MwFAXg9/6K81LSrnsqexrICGprqolFrdayF8fSVWhtqb7s17sibHgYSOAL8Z57o7fv7nRtlv3Ree/P1eXjs0L7bB2BqoFtvurG2rt4FQrVRSwEmmsnnmat44g4EfOFRX1Ei7oRWhlXRvKA1M2wirCWKJQMUw/ah36sEtroFDoOS@jM@DB5tocJYDYwJYwHNw6U5yNOsJWJirDLkD@qPJ4cRSnsubWiOFUd6nbavomp7W/3uulwnA3NTAZN/vZk9Ls3KCQdSMlYriTFpGwszx9rRXlrqhKosZRHoveUIVGVMCWVY0V0UlNnmvI0n6TONKVrytN0E5puwlCeyUkBaUPSJJrIuCSaIaaaMX3bLc2X0Hwp1UypZkazZ/uxdjRtzqK8gkU3UVAvRfn/n31Zinn/Aw)

Comment: You only use `u` in `if s in u` can you note use it directly instead of declaring it?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yup, just doing that right now lol.

Comment: @totallyhuman that string compression is pretty amazing, nice one!

Comment: @totallyhuman `VALA WAZ NCA COH CTX SDE FL GA HID WIL MIN IAKSC KY ME MD MA MNMS MOK MTNE NH NJ NY ND PARI UT NVT WV WY` is the smallest I can make it

Comment: `'MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY'`

Comment: The above string is still shorter

Comment: Whoops, sorry it took me so long. Seems I have lost as copying that string doesn't make my answer better than the one using it. Please stop upvoting this and upvote the other better answer.

Comment: @totallyhuman I'll upvote your comment instead for being a good sport

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 184 bytes

```java
s->s.format(s.equals("OR")?"I am not%s":"MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY".contains(s)?"I am%s":"What is%s?"," an engineer")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZLfbqJAFMbvfYovk5hAojxAu7WZglaqMzRApXazF7MWXVwFlhmbNI3P7g4HqxfzA86f75szw1Z9qOH2/e@p2NdVY7C1397BFDtvfShXpqhKb3J@ue2tdkprCFWU@OoB9eH3rlhBG2Xs46Mq3rG3OScxTVFufv6CajbapVLgW@VHlx2ge46wxt1JD0faW1fNXhlHe/m/g9pph0Uxc@9ZCLVHWZm@ZjdMhNLncw6R@KkUcsFnS2T8Dc88xmSORw45DQP40SwJIMYQgV22PH2FHEM@QS4hbSaaIg45XlJkC7vCObIl81ZVaewA2tFnX/LM/iiDQvf1PRswqBJ5uSnKPG@Ye7ql2S4Dm1wbjbvzyADjczawnBHfiHFLnxMjYtoyGLecUP2jzX4rTMM2EgZEyoaSSAqzhLhsOaeIIB0RXBVEFycdQb2CugS5C3KX1CUXxCnx6aogBUXIRfpE2k9ElRFNF9Fcz@QVk1fiXxUSqk/JPX1t@UK@i47UlXWkPWSkYO/kosAp@/BAJ@YzCh@747c/zvmfowu46a7BvdxC8qlNvveqg/FqW2XWDgP6GsORZb@0im3DAGtP1fXu02m/XLfTPvbadTz9Bw)

I apologize for reusing the compressed string: I couldn't find anything better by myself... :(

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>104</s> <s>103</s> 101 bytes

```
„€À€ˆ„I€Ü‚.•~Zµ∞/'—¶[@øl•Œ2ù.•9₆\|&×ƒΩ#àöF},cΓ páe;ð²∍₆jÌn#dÅ?DvĆ8A•2ôìuIå©è¹„ORQi'€–}„€¤©É)ðýª'?®_×J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcO8R01rDjcAidNtQI4niDfnUcMsvUcNi@qiDm191DFPX/1Rw5RD26IdDu/IAYoenWR0eCdI2vJRU1tMjdrh6ccmnVupfHjB4W1utTrJ5yYrFBxemGp9eMOhTY86eoFqsg735CmnHG61dyk70mbhCNRpdHjL4TWlnoeXHlp5eMWhnUB7/YMCM9WBdj9qmFwLcdOhJUDJTs3DGw7vPbRK3f7QuvjD073@//cPAgA)

Old 104 byte version in case that is more easily improved.

```
„€À€ˆ„I€Ü‚.•ÂkXñ…ΓVt€Ïè∍‡Λi„2¶’að=–½6™oÑþÁāõgO·ð~
λ†₃›;â&ÄFv¾‡1~ǝQa«;cS•u2ôIå©è¹„ORQi'€–}„€¤©É)ðýª'?®_×J
```

Not happy with the compression nor the special case for `?`.

Comment: OK what is this? Did you just re-order the states or something?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: The 104 byte version is just a compression of the numbers corresponding to the characters positions in the alphabet `(A=1,C=3 ...)`. The 103 byte version does the same for some states and merge some states that end in the same letter that a new state starts with. I'm sure this can still be improved and I'll add a better explanation when I've golfed it more.

Comment: Nice answer! I like the `.•~Zµ∞/'—¶[@øl•Œ2ù` you've used for some of the states, instead of just compressing all the states and doing the `2ô`. And nice approach overall. (Glad I saw your answer before attempting something myself, because it definitely wouldn't have been as short..)

Answer (score 4):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org), <strike>222</strike> 211 bytes

```
let f v=let(a,b)=if"OR"=v then("I am not",".")elif"WALAKSCARINMNVTNCTX NHIDE MOHIL COKY MSD PAZ WIA WVA FL GA MA MD ME MI MT NE ND NJ NY UT WY".Contains v then("I am",".")else("What is","?")in a+" an engineer"+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/haoNAEIT/5ymGhYKSVPIAteVQ21zjncHYWBvy4wJnchDPokegT28vgUKHhYX5BnanHR@73vbTdNEOLa6x34FaHMPYtFSUFF/hztoGxKE62N7RgiIK9cXjmuVsvU1YyaWQu0om1SfkiqcZRLHiOZJi3UBsU2zYF2rOUO8YXnO8MQg/KYRPcogKMoNMId8hG3xUqBuKkt46ZeyI/w/8HR91QPVZOZjRWy8UGgs1JygLbU/Gaj3Q/DjtnzLrhp9Nb6x7PsxuFTt1iw6nK@IZvL4Hz1oLehgJQXtH0X55CO90OU1F@Qs)

Expanded:

```
let f v =
    let (a,b) =
        if "OR" = v then ("I am not",".")
        elif "WALAKSCARINMNVTNCTX NHIDE MOHIL COKY MSD PAZ WIA WVA FL GA MA MD ME MI MT NE ND NJ NY UT WY".Contains v then ("I am",".")
        else ("What is","?")
    a + " an engineer" + b
```

Given a two-letter state *v* passed to the function *f*, build a tuple *(a, b)* representing the head and tail of the "engineer" sentence.

Feel free to use the "compressed state string" freely; it's one whole byte shorter than the MINCALA one...

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>109</s> 96 bytes

```r
function(x)sub("#"," an engineer",c("I am not#","I am#","What is#?"))[2-x%in%state.abb+!x=="OR"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfbvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO4NElDSVlJR0khMU8hNS89My81tUhJJ1lDyVMhMVchL78EJAlig@jwjMQShcxiZXslTc1oI90K1cw81eKSxJJUvcSkJG3FCltbJf8gpdj/6RogWpMLSDt6Q2knJc3/AA)

13 bytes thanks to J.Doe - through use of regex and indexation.

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfbvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO4NElDSVlJR0khMU8hNS89My81tUhJJ1lDKTwjsUQhs1jZHijpqZCYqwylFfLyS5SVNDWjK1Qz81SLSxJLUvUSk5K0NSpsbZX8g5Q0tQ1j/6drgJlcQNrRG0o7KWn@BwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @J.Doe `sub` is much better, thank you!

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfbvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO4NElDSVlJR0khMU8hNS89My81tUhJJ1lDyVMhMVchL78EJAlig@jwjMQShcxiZXslTc1oI90K1cw81eKSxJJUvcSkJG3FCltbJf8gpdj/6RogWpMLSDt6Q2knJc3/AA "R – Try It Online")  

Comment: @J.Doe Of course!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>136</s> <s>135</s> <s>131</s> <s>129</s> 128 bytes

More savings may be available by experimenting with the order of the state abbreviations - I'll come back to that in a while.

```
`mnnmlãGLÏz¯¬ct¸flgaá[9¨kyµmçpCijmsmtnhnvnyn¬kpÂÉcsdk¡x©vavt°±wvwy`ò øUv)?"I am {¥"OR"?"not ":P}"+` à¨\ `:`Wt   à¨\?
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YG1ubm1sheNHTM96r6xjdLhmbGdhluFbOahrebVt53BDaWptc210mJpuaG52bnlurJdrjnDCyWNzZGuheKl2YXZ0sLF3dnd5YPIg+FV2KT8iSSBhbSB7pSJPUiI/Im5vdCAiOlB9IitghCDgCKhcIGA6YFeVdCCJIIQg4AioXD8=&input=Ik9SIg==)

---

### Explanation

- We take a compressed string of the lowercased abbreviations, decompress it, and split it into an array of 2 character strings using the `ò` method.
- We then use the `ø` method to see if the array contains `Uv`, which is the input string converted to lowercase.
- If we so, we build our output string, beginning with `"I am "`
- Checking if the input string `¥` (is equal to) `"OR"` allows us to append either `"not "` or the empty string variable `P`.
- And then we decompress and append the compressed string `"an engineer"`.
- If the input was not found in the array, then we output the decompression of compressed string `"What is an engineer?"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 143 bytes

```
"ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY"q#g"I am not 
I am 
What is?"N/=)" an engineer"\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsIwFAX3PcUjrlx5ApFPW21s8ytpbKy4CRJqhUbU3j8GF8MbeHN/ujlG0WpJUJJzatJ2uWHFPdUDLF1xIo19gwOBK1kgb@uugCqhikTKzQVcgo/gAZyetsLZwPYJ2cAO4r0ahYSbEV4Lsr9l9uEWTN@d4M12LeACfBin4P1H3GIk/QM) or as a [test suite](https://tio.run/##HZDNbsIwEITvPMXKVQ899Y5UVcYBYpJdo8TEhIKqqIoolUilwq3qs6c7OfizvTM7/vn46q7jmwmVIWNLoAAOAGrOAgGIimypWMG3hpB7hc8A1LwAEIoaaBUltow2ho@nLdoYZoaPEc@IF/ikAXJgAzCAKHEAUgLUgJtukVchr4ZaQ41IjnvFDqHNBPjSBMQndCSEWtQWCzzQmdPvu5mTOY76Id4Se3G21Ll2UVgaW7SU7IG2tqJVSWtLkvuMXCjqjHhJnOlQe9yTLEk2JC2JKiGnXaTU6PAl6bHHh7Px1F1p@L7TbFrN0md3p8vt1cjzy5OhbqB@OF@Gvv/R@5xuw9/j@A8)

#### Explanation

```
"ORIA...."       e# Push a string in which every state is a substring, but no non-state is
                 e# a substring.
q                e# Read the input.
#                e# Find the index of the input in the string. (-1 if not found)
g                e# Signum of the index: -1 for negative, 0 for 0, 1 for positive.
"I am.... "      e# Push this string. Note the trailing space on the first two lines of it.
N/               e# Split it on newlines.
=                e# Get the string at index given by the signum.
)                e# Pull out the last character.
" an engineer"\  e# Push " an engineer" and bring the other character to the TOS.
                 e# Implicit output.
```

Since Oregon (`OR`) is at the start of the string, finding the signum of the index of the input in that will be -1 if not found, 0 if `OR`, 1 if any other state. Which string to print can be decided by that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>180</s> <s>179</s> 178 bytes

```python
def f(s):e=" not"*(s=="OR")+" an engineer";return"I am"+e if s in"PALAKSCAZ CTNMINCOR FL GA MDE ME MND MA MSD MOKY NE NH NJ NY WA OHID UTX MTNVARIA WIL WVT WY"else"What is"+e+"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FZHBbsIwEETP7VeM9pQUq5feqFBlJbQxxHaVhAS4IdUUSzSgJD306@kg@clez@54V77@TadL/3K7fYUjjsmYzsNC0F8meUrGxUJ8JelMcOgR@u/YhzDI6xCm36EXg8OPzALiESNiL5@61Os603tkjbPGZb7Ce4kPDZsvYblcDsuo5ubXO7glXAG3gtuh0/CFybFptrCNa3VlNDpTomsbdDsJ5zFIdzpMiCMfncmb3I6XAZEvQ3SpoNdkTyqFTBNPGoV8qdiGYh8KhVEwOWFsHOHduiY7hZJny1xL3d7PzLXMsdQtvSy9HHXXkoKsiCWsdRlhnee9Zx@ePXzSo6JHTa2m1tCr2SpOqNDeod7doV/HvI4@W@rVhjOQpZHn8XqOUyIKks4fH65D7KckKv5TTNPbPw)

Comment: Yep, it's correct: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZFBT4NAEIXP5VdMOUFcTdSbiYcNtBZhoQFsS41piN3iJrg0sI3x1@Pb2AOHlyw7M@99w55/zVenH8fB1EYO9EwuTxjxGNpDOaOAQxlUMgoXjJaov@BuFTGKQgjfUQrhLi6gilGCs0CvQF3YM3oFegTqAl4CXinq6QZaQa@QgDCbBhDmMtxn4MjAsIZHDo8CtQK1El7ljtEbfDZWqG@t4LdF37Zy74Zzq4znMnJ957tu1OdhML3Sjd1xzRMeFwHfY6tURGmQ5dgLa4F4AXLAhgAHr/3M4gq0AAUnEJEEuChE@g6bpBueRxyxCeJLGz2eatUiZlm3g3ROXU@KlKa@1o30Wqm9KY5/e@8/OTPz0x1aaYzs7SNMG97Vk7p5@HBm6kSeSy7pzli7yYRPtT6SN/W4Nv0/qw2YnWGG/1F1F7J88jh3mWJTFzRdycv@Ih3kWRd7hfnJeN1LBJLUjdJS9nPXH8c/ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [166 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY9Bb4JAEIXP7a94mcQE66aX3kxMswFaVtjFAIJoPdBUK4miES799fSZ7JedmTfzdvb2N5yu3dt4XHyN5@by/dOgn@@kOjUD2n7Sv4sSg@YiM0F3HeTF6xcLSTOZzmTSy37Xo@1kpRMd577ewi@cNc5PM3wk@NSwQQjL4wJYZjmvNK7hQrglXI1KI41MgHWxgS1cqTOjUZkEVVm4CFUt@4mg6XDoftvucLjLeLze0fJViE4UdEy2JFPwNUlJoRCEiiso7qAQGQUTEObGEdbinNQKCWPLXkvdPmL2WvZY6pZell6OuitJRJbEEs46n3AuZT3lHil3WNEjo0dOLadW0KvYKH5QoXxAvXpAv4p9FX021LM1/0BCI6/97dwOnijIdP78dLu33eC1CkevnU7Hfw "Python 3 – Try It Online"). I'm sure the string can also be tightened up a liitle more by reusing states

Comment: Thanks @JoKing. It resembles the Python 2 answer too much at this point IMO :). I've been trying to compress the string, but the shortest I could get was 92 symbols. I've written [a short script](https://repl.it/@tungmetal/State-compression) to do that, but it can only cut it down to 94 characters, and it doesn't compress optimally. I also think that in this particular challenge the magic string itself should not be included in the byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>220</strike> <strike>214</strike> <strike>210</strike> 209 bytes

```hs
s(a:b:c)=[a,b]:s(b:c)
s _=[]
a="I am "
e="an engineer "
i"OR"=a++"not "++e
i x|x`elem`s"MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY"=a++e
i _="What is "++e++"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZDNjoIwFIX3PsVJVxqYFzBhJg34g9JiAEV0jNYJGckIY6wLF/PuDBwX/ZLe@/Wethdjf8rrtW3t0IzP46@Rtzfu@TC2w34zsDh6@8PAeCKEqSEGpSdMg7L5rpqyvHeFSsSJ8IzjiOb3AeE45aDC8@95Kq9lfbJChdqXkYRK/UwrvZHLArncYSUTTCPMJPQ8DODHyzSAmkAF3er0bAs9gV5AF9BdJ54jCSXWGfJNt8IIecHcPu/oifxiHqgsb9Bd5kO0takaeKjNTR0x/LR4e8ftXjUPDK1bwY5G2AsZCRdCLskdmfT0JRmTWc9g0nNKf8buPOwZBiTroSbZXaZk0TNiRXGCoq9eFU5QPKXoKyYqJmr6ekPOyQWpSE7WPsmZMZ2Yb4n5ihVTEqakNFOaGROzbc81szYv0s9fZG7Os91XuyKKxKH9Bw)

Comment: otherwise = True, `1<2` is even shorter

Comment: *Facepalm*, thanks!

Comment: You have included `OR` in the long string in the second definition of i

Comment: I stole the long string from the other answers. OR isn't part of it though?

Comment: No, not anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 188 Bytes

```php
$e=" an engineer";echo strpos(_TNNMLAALAKAZARCACOCTDEFLGAHIIDILINIAKSKYMEMDMAMIMNMSMOMTNENVNHNJNYNCNDOHOKORPARISCSDTXUTVTVAWAWVWIWY,$argn)&1?"I am".($argn!="OR"?"":" not").$e:"What is$e?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc5Ba4MwFADg@35F9pDRQins2k7kkdj6pnkZmpray5ARag@LQf3/bvT6nb44xPUji0N8SfrpHlKwVziuiU9B9EH4cH8E7yc4@p9hFPMyxXHefFtmXSFWWOINa4nSSKvyU3XGgkhRRUxYNmWnc600atKsG2205ZxbLviTO5asTGFKU39hTY1slL1ebGtbdOhaR67bPT/bt/cMSPS/sN884TUFU0MGcAARxgW2@8QfwA39Ih5z4rP//PoH)

Comment: `in_array(...)` to `strpos(_AKALARAZCACOCTDEFLGAHIIAIDILINKSKYLAMAMDMEMIMNMOMSMTNCNDNENHNJNMNVNYOHOKPARISCSDTNTXUTVAVTWAWIWVWY,$argn)&1`.

Comment: @Christoph works not for an Input for example of LA

Comment: Hm right :/ maybe we can reorder the string a bit .. I'll try. Also invalidates the js answer btw.

Comment: `_NMMNINTNRIHIMIWISCNCCTMTUTVTWVNVFLILCAALGAIAMAPAVAWACOLAMOAKARKSMSNHOHOKORAZDEIDKYMEMDNENJNYNDSDTXWY` works

Comment: @Christoph Or my order work too.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 178 bytes

```
s=>(s=="OR"?"I am notx":"MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PARIA FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY".Contains(s)?"I amx":"What isx?").Replace("x"," an engineer");
```

[Run in C# Pad](http://csharppad.com/gist/2df8b77923d66e3f083078065bab4b6f)

Golf based on [Mayube's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124148/70241); new here, so I don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Might want to edit in a link in to his solution :) If you click share on his solution, it gives you a link straight to it.

Comment: @StephenS Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 204

```
s=>{h=/^(A[LKZR]|C[AOT]|DE|FL|[GPLV]A|[HR]I|I[DLNA]|K[SY]|M[EDAINSOT]|N[EVHJMYCD]|O[HK]|S[CD]|T[NX]|[VU]T|W[AVIY]|(OR))$/.exec(s);return(!h?"What is ":"I am "+(h[2]?"not ":""))+"an engineer"+(!h?'?':'')}
```

Comment: Pure optimize ```s=>(!(h=/(A[LKZR]|C[AOT]|DE|FL|[GPLV]A|[HR]I|I[DLNA]|K[SY]|M[EDAINSOT]|N[EVHJMYCD]|O[HKR]|S[CD]|T[NX]|[VU]T|W[AVIY])/.test(s))?"What is":"I am"+(s=='OR'?" not":""))+" an engineer"+['?'[+h]]```

Comment: @l4m2 nice, that's got my answer beat.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 173 bytes

```
s->(!"MINCALARIA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY OR".contains(s)?"What is":"I am"+(s.equals("OR")?" not":""))+" an engineer"
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! All entries must be a full program or a function; I believe you can turn this into a valid lambda expression (and therefore function) by adding `s->` to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 189 bytes

```
/A[LKZR]|C[AOT]|DE|FL|[GPV]A|HI|I[DLNA]|KS|KY|LA|M[EDAINSOT]|N[EVHJMYCD]|O[HKR]|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|W[AVIY]/{print"I am "($0~OR?"not ":"")"an engineer";exit}
{print"What is an engineer?"}
```

If input matches a regex containing all the state abbreviations, print "I am an engineer" with a 'not' inserted in the middle if the state is Oregon, then exit.

If the input does not match the regex, it must not be a US state abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 238 bytes

```
def f(x):s=x in('ALAKAZARCACOCTDEFLGAHIIDILINIAKSKYLAMEMDMAMIMNMSMOMTNENVNHNJNMNYNCNDOHOKORPARISCSDTNTXUTVTVAWAWVWIWY'[i:i+2]for i in range(0,100,2));o=x=='OR';q=(1-o)*(1-s);return q*'What is'+(1-q)*('I am'+o*' not')+' an engineer'+q*'?'
```

#### Explanation

No compression techniques used.

```
def f(x):
    # Check if State
    s = x in ('ALAK...WIWY'[i:i+2]
              for i in range(0, 100, 2))

    # Check if Oregon
    o = x == 'OR'

    # Check if neither Oregon nor State
    q = (1-o) * (1-s)

    # Construct output string
    return q * 'What is' + \
        (1-q) * ('I am' + o * ' not') + \
        ' an engineer' + \
        q * '?'
```

Comment: It's Oregon, not Ohio.

Comment: @L3viathan Not sure how I mess that up after seeing Oregon everywhere due to _Life is Strange_... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 100 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

This language postdates the challenge.  But the author (me) didn't see it until now.

```
éë&W≈#W¬π█▐╜╣╟◙√a☻∞ZrπU♫ÿô♠▌⌠Që≡AûpI⌡ÄNAç¶µ↑╝╣òøΩ.¬É]╩Æ↓d∩é¡2Å²eB┼¼▬5∟┤sW♠♂↑q▐WMï╝|Ñ↑╫+3¼↔îûvlLΩ∟┬oë
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82892657f72357aae3dbdebdb9c70afb6102ec5a72e3550e989306ddf45189f041967049f58e4e418714e618bcb99500ea2eaa905dca921964ef82ad328ffd6542c5ac16351cb47357060b1871de574d8bbc7ca518d72b33ac1d8c96766c4cea1cc26f89&i=AL%0AOR%0AKA%0Aor%0Aal&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>175</s>171 Bytes

```
x=>[`What is${e=" an engineer"}?`,`I am${x=="OR"?" not"+e:e}`][+!!'MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY'.match(x)]
```

Joined lots of good

## Or 152 bytes on ISO encoding

Generator:

```
'x=>[`What is${e=" an engineer"}?`,`I am${x=="OR"?" not"+e:e}`][+!!btoa`*`.match(x)]'.replace('*',atob('MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY '.replace(/ /g,'/')))
```

Comment: It might be possible to rearrange the string so using btoa to expand

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 0+176 bytes

```c
-Dz"=an engineer" -Df(s)*s-79|1[s]-82?strstr("MINCALA=MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY",s)?"I am"z:"What is"z"?":"I am not"z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BToQwGIRfZfKfWiMHvahrNqSB1a1AMSwugvHQEEASt5otXlBf3W41Mdlk5vDNzGHaYGhb59xOj4bxz/ePybKeUV4Q59f/VNXHlCfH1DS/9O1@2v5VD9YF8bwkaIPODKPpuj35qGeWL09scHH1dfZkn4PL89BOey9GmVSRSAWyTVSqTG1FUqMSDe5FgZsUtwJqLWNEebKJka2Qxd5@Xj5CraDuoGoo3@RrFFLgoUS19ZYp/OtTy0OS0DuaF1S96AmjpZlCWvylMG8TzQc)

pure translate

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 175 bytes

```
(('I am'+' not'*!($i='ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY'.IndexOf($args))+($e=' an engineer')),"What is$e`?")[!++$i]
```

Test script:

```
$f = {

$e=' an engineer'
$i='ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY'.IndexOf($args)
(('I am'+' not'*!$i+$e),"What is$e`?")[!++$i]

# Important! OR is a first state in the modified @totallyhuman's genuis string

}

@(
    ,('OR', 'I am not an engineer')
    ,('AL', 'I am an engineer')
    ,('IL', 'I am an engineer')
    ,('ZZ', 'What is an engineer?')
) | % {
    $s,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $s
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```
True: I am not an engineer
True: I am an engineer
True: I am an engineer
True: What is an engineer?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>236</s> <s>182</s> 181 bytes

```python
lambda s:'I am not'+e if s=='OR'else'I am'+e if s in'MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY'else'What is%s?'%e
e=' an engineer'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBb4JAEIXv/RXvYlZTb72ZkGYDKivsYgBBbHug6VJJFI1w6a@n@2h6mC@ZeW/eTvb@M5xv3cvYeO/jpb5@ftXoV0KhvqK7DeLZom3Qe55IUmEvvZ2k/zHaTmhlfBlL6MzPjTaFjCqU8oS9TLGJsZUwoQrgJ1EWQK@hA1fOnh9h1jA7mArGKUmIVEkccpSFKxWjrP5eLM/1gLaf9a9iZp@sJ1B3sN1321n7EGNze6B2l@BNSCmWPHQpZExExIngzKfqJ0TuEKwdNvRtKYTKQQUEZ8oQFKKMqBxitpprmj49tVzTNGv6NOM14w19piBCYkdoglHGJ5iSUE146Z55KfMyqhnVnMn50eHA0GICfeUExpfccH/1sXrC/dF2w7yZ14vF@As)

TIO contains test cases for all the states.
-54 bytes thanks to the string compression

Comment: You can use the string compression from the other answers to save bytes

Comment: `MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY` is better compression

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 174 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{a:" an engineer?";$[(#:)l:ss["ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY";x];-1_"I am",$[l~(),0;" not";""],a;"What is",a]}
```

**Explanation:**

```
  {
  // save string into variable a
  a:" an engineer?";
  // try to find the input x in the condensed string, save location in variable l, $ is a if/else
  $[(#:)l:ss["ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY";x];
  // found a match, check if it was at index 0 ('OR') and inject " not" if so, drop the '?' off the end
  -1_"I am",$[l~(),0;" not";""],a;
  // otherwise return 'What is an engineer?'
  "What is",a]
  }
```

**Notes:**

Used the 'compressed' string from other answers, struggling to find a way to bring it into a single line in order to avoid assignment of the `a` variable (yet still add the `?` when input is not a state.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 175 bytes

```
..
I am $&~MINCALAZ SCT FL GA WIAKSD ME MD MA MNMS MOKY MTNE NVTX NH NJ NY ND COHIDE PARIL UT VA WA WV WY
(..)~.*\1.*
~
OR~.*
not ~
I am ..~.*
What is ~?
~
an engineer
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU5BCsIwALv3FTmozB0KvkDKNre6tZWtbk482EPRHawwd@7Xa0UIIYQkZLbL5ExYJ@U9UEo4zAurjRdcZqxhV3SZxqFByTBwVnc5RAERmUFI0UGoeoTQsoDs9QWygjxCjpA5MlXxvMCJtbzBWaOPExE9hpEklG49TW87mhJPVBs1ce8F/n@A0p8xPM2C6QO/jxnjYN1jctbOIaiKKBFrXw) Hopefully I've appropriated the best state list. Explanation:

```
..
I am $&~MINCALAZ SCT FL GA WIAKSD ME MD MA MNMS MOKY MTNE NVTX NH NJ NY ND COHIDE PARIL UT VA WA WV WY
```

Start building up the result. Also, insert the state list for use by the next stage.

```
(..)~.*\1.*
~
```

If it's one of the 49 states, delete the state and list.

```
OR~.*
not ~
```

If it's Oregon, replace the state with `not`, and delete the list.

```
I am ..~.*
What is ~?
```

If it's anything else, replace everything with the other output.

```
~
an engineer
```

Add these word in last to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

## Crystal, <strike>232 207</strike> 205 Bytes

```
i="ORALAKAZARCACOCTDEFLGAHIIDILINIAKSKYLAMEMDMAMIMNMSMOMTNENVNHNJNMNYNCNDOHOKPARISCSDTNTXUTVTVAWAWVWIWY".split(/(..)/).index ARGV[0];p (i ?"I am ": "What is ")+(i==1 ?"not ": "")+"an engineer"+(i ?"": "?")
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Hc1Bb4IwGMbxr9K8J4gZZtcZYt60KBX6doFKx24Na2YTrUY4uA@@M2Nen1@e/If7zzi58zyHHHSDNVb4iQ1HrrkRxa7eYymlkLUkiVVb9TWqQgmFSipSrdLKUEEdlXQgRT1xErrU1Ts2suWtMGQ@jqYzHVq0nZW2h2y8ncOUrJMsS9dpFuKXf7AlDZsbSwLbgmTuwuCNgT25iYWRQbpKQp6/Lhav05OWCVxkPn6H6P0dVs/nv2whneffeH0Z3HDyfw). (slightly modified due to an issue of ARGV)

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 135 bytes

```
USE: usa-cities [ " an engineer"swap [ "I am"swap string>state OR = 
[ " not"append ] when ""] [ 2drop "What is" "?"] recover surround ]
```

More readable, and named:

```
: engineer? ( state-name -- str ) 
  [ " an engineer" ] dip ! put this below the input on the stack 
  [ 
    [ "I am" ] dip       ! put this below the input too but above the other 
    string>state OR =    ! string>state throws on a non-state name 
    [ " not" append ] when ""  ! otherwise and if it is OR, append this 
  ] 
  [ 2drop "What is" "?" ] recover surround ; ! catch error, surround string
```

`[ x ] dip` and `x swap` are equivalent in stack effect but the first is shorter only when nested: `[ [ [ x ] dip ] dip ] dip`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>213</s> <s>211</s> 194 Bytes

```
c="uTXnMSCORIDEwVAKYmTNHILfLAZpALmNEmOKSDwINCARmEwAnJnDmAmIAgAwYcTnVToHnYmD"
r=(lambda x:x in c or x[0].lower()+x[1]in c)(i)^1
u="What is "*r+("I am "+"not "*(i=="OR"))*(r^1)+"an engineer"+"?"*r
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##FYvdSsMwFIDv9xSHc5WsINZLIUhYC4urLXRlWscmsdYtsJyUmJL69LXefj/Db7g6epiN8Dp@GBrGwPjcCRybN3rZb6paZXk8yF1rm3Kriu9Cvg@ysGVuq90@i6rcyNrmUdIzZVZaJS8ytl1Dh8ZtqbUZrrxgN20/vzRMjxMYgg6ch@l4f7q7udh7xpPpmJ7@BWeGn9PVKPD1qgOYH8C1Txgq0BYwQXJhIcwIgVWNnK@ZP6c8QU3Q08VQ3/ulelqmefCGAoxzVf8B)

**Stuff i'm working on shortening:**

- `(i=="OR")`
- `or x[0].lower()+x[1]in c`

**Update:**

- Saved 2 Bytes by replacing `s=not r` with `s=r^1`
- Separated header and footer of code

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 164 bytes

```
->s{r="What is an engineer?"
j=379
"##(*Q0'7q;N>%*$o(.F%#&'#&#5##%$%+%5%)5r@#P,B353*/%".bytes{|i|s==(j+=i-34).to_s(36).upcase&&r="I am not"[0,i==41?8:4]+r[7,12]}
r}
```

Uses a run length encoding, therefore magic string is 50 bytes long, one per state. In order to build this, it was first necessary to put the state codes in alphabetical order of state code, rather than state name. Unfortunately 7 bytes are needed to convert the base36 representation of `j` from a lowercase statecode into an uppercase statecode.

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
f=->s{                                                  #s is the input string.
  r="What is an engineer?"                              #Set r to "What is an engineer?"
  j=379                                                 #Set j to one less than 380, which in base36 becomes AK, the first statecode alphabetically
  "##(*Q0'7q;N>%*$o(.F%#&'#&#5##%$%+%5%)5r@#P,B353*/%". #Iterate through the run length encoded string 
  bytes{|i|                                             #(each character represents how far in base 36 each state code is from the previous one)
    s==(j+=i-34).to_s(36).upcase&&                      #take the ascii value of the character and subtract 34 (example #=35-34=1) and add to j. Convert j to base36 to get a state code.
      r="I am not"[0,i==41?8:4]+r[7,12]                 #if the state code matches s, modify r. Take the first 4 characters of "I am not" (first 8 in the case of OR where i==41) 
  }                                                     #and add r[7,12]==" an engineer" (12 characters of the existing value of r, starting at character 7 
r}                                                      #return r

%w{AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY XX}.map{|i|p [i,f[i]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## **/// (Slashes), 2102 bytes**

```
/*/\/-\/\///$/\/,\/\///OR/_not .//AL*AK*AZ*AR*CA*CO*CT*DE*FL*GA*HI*ID*IL*IN*IA*KS*KY*LA*ME*MD*MA*MI*MN*MS*MO*MT*NE*NV*NH*NJ*NM*NY*NC*ND*OH*OK*PA*RI*SC*SD*TN*TX*UT*VT*VA*WA*WV*WI*WY*AA$AB$AC$AD$AE$AF$AG$AH$AI$AJ$AM$AN$AO$AP$AQ$AS$AT$AU$AV$AW$AX$AY$BA$BB$BC$BD$BE$BF$BG$BH$BI$BJ$BK$BL$BM$BN$BO$BP$BQ$BR$BS$BT$BU$BV$BW$BX$BY$BZ$CB$CC$CD$CE$CF$CG$CH$CI$CJ$CK$CL$CM$CN$CP$CQ$CR$CS$CU$CV$CW$CX$CY$CZ$DA$DB$DC$DD$DF$DG$DH$DI$DJ$DK$DL$DM$DN$DO$DP$DQ$DR$DS$DT$DU$DV$DW$DX$DY$DZ$EA$EB$EC$ED$EE$EF$EG$EH$EI$EJ$EK$EL$EM$EN$EO$EP$EQ$ER$ES$ET$EU$EV$EW$EX$EY$EZ$FA$FB$FC$FD$FE$FF$FG$FH$FI$FJ$FK$FM$FN$FO$FP$FQ$FR$FS$FT$FU$FV$FW$FX$FY$FZ$GB$GC$GD$GE$GF$GG$GH$GI$GJ$GK$GL$GM$GN$GO$GP$GQ$GR$GS$GT$GU$GV$GW$GX$GY$GZ$HA$HB$HC$HD$HE$HF$HG$HH$HJ$HK$HL$HM$HN$HO$HP$HQ$HR$HS$HT$HU$HV$HW$HX$HY$HZ$IB$IC$IE$IF$IG$IH$II$IJ$IK$IM$IO$IP$IQ$IR$IS$IT$IU$IV$IW$IX$IY$IZ$JA$JB$JC$JD$JE$JF$JG$JH$JI$JJ$JK$JL$JM$JN$JO$JP$JQ$JR$JS$JT$JU$JV$JW$JX$JY$JZ$KA$KB$KC$KD$KE$KF$KG$KH$KI$KJ$KK$KL$KM$KN$KO$KP$KQ$KR$KT$KU$KV$KW$KX$KZ$LB$LC$LD$LE$LF$LG$LH$LI$LJ$LK$LL$LM$LN$LO$LP$LQ$LR$LS$LT$LU$LV$LW$LX$LY$LZ$MB$MC$MF$MG$MH$MJ$MK$ML$MM$MP$MQ$MR$MU$MV$MW$MX$MY$MZ$NA$NB$NF$NG$NI$NK$NL$NN$NO$NP$NQ$NR$NS$NT$NU$NW$NX$NZ$OA$OB$OC$OD$OE$OF$OG$OI$OJ$OL$OM$ON$OO$OP$OQ$OS$OT$OU$OV$OW$OX$OY$OZ$PB$PC$PD$PE$PF$PG$PH$PI$PJ$PK$PL$PM$PN$PO$PP$PQ$PR$PS$PT$PU$PV$PW$PX$PY$PZ$QA$QB$QC$QD$QE$QF$QG$QH$QI$QJ$QK$QL$QM$QN$QO$QP$QQ$QR$QS$QT$QU$QV$QW$QX$QY$QZ$RA$RB$RC$RD$RE$RF$RG$RH$RJ$RK$RL$RM$RN$RO$RP$RQ$RR$RS$RT$RU$RV$RW$RX$RY$RZ$SA$SB$SE$SF$SG$SH$SI$SJ$SK$SL$SM$SN$SO$SP$SQ$SR$SS$ST$SU$SV$SW$SX$SY$SZ$TA$TB$TC$TD$TE$TF$TG$TH$TI$TJ$TK$TL$TM$TO$TP$TQ$TR$TS$TT$TU$TV$TW$TY$TZ$UA$UB$UC$UD$UE$UF$UG$UH$UI$UJ$UK$UL$UM$UN$UO$UP$UQ$UR$US$UU$UV$UW$UX$UY$UZ$VB$VC$VD$VE$VF$VG$VH$VI$VJ$VK$VL$VM$VN$VO$VP$VQ$VR$VS$VU$VV$VW$VX$VY$VZ$WB$WC$WD$WE$WF$WG$WH$WJ$WK$WL$WM$WN$WO$WP$WQ$WR$WS$WT$WU$WW$WX$WZ$XA$XB$XC$XD$XE$XF$XG$XH$XI$XJ$XK$XL$XM$XN$XO$XP$XQ$XR$XS$XT$XU$XV$XW$XX$XY$XZ$YA$YB$YC$YD$YE$YF$YG$YH$YI$YJ$YK$YL$YM$YN$YO$YP$YQ$YR$YS$YT$YU$YV$YW$YX$YY$YZ$ZA$ZB$ZC$ZD$ZE$ZF$ZG$ZH$ZI$ZJ$ZK$ZL$ZM$ZN$ZO$ZP$ZQ$ZR$ZS$ZT$ZU$ZV$ZW$ZX$ZY$ZZ$-/_.//_/I am //./an engineer//,/What is .?/
```

**[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JZXLCua2AUZfZRZnZZL8j1BsybpbV8uSRSDMIjSBNoVO3n86UDgczurbft/@9fXbH79/@/79s31@/fz86w99PvzwT//PVD@//fWfv7/88vnsYdv9tq9tr5vYN5E2cW/y3FTY9L4Zu1m52bDZuNl9823z7xb27Tq3S27Xj7DbFberbVfarnuL5xafLZotui1eW3y3KLYot2S25Le8b9VuTWxNbnfc7rn1e3t@sG/jB8827Dbebd/ZD3bBLtlPdsWu2Q27ZXfsF3tkT@yZvbA39pu9sz/sg32yvxw7x8EhOCTHyaE4NIfhsByOw3MEjosjciSOzFE4KkfjuDk6x8MxOCbHj6mFOBACIREnQiE0wiAswiE8IiAuRERkREFUREN0xIMYiIl4EQu5Iw@kQEqkQmqkQVqkQ3pkQF7IiEzIjCzIimzIG9mRD3IgJ/JFLs6d8@AUnJLz5FScmtNwWk7H6TkD58UZORNn5iyclbNx3pyd8@EcnJPz5VyoHXWgBEqiTpRCaZRBWZRDedSFiqiEyqiCqqiGulEd9aAGaqJe1EIfaIGW6BOt0Bpt0Bbt0B4d0Bc6ohM6owu6ohv6Rnf0gx7oiX7RC7NjDozASMyJURiNMRiH8ZiAuTARkzAZUzAV0zA3pmMezMBMzItZ2AMrsCdWYTXWYC3WYT32wiZsxhZsxTbsje3YBzuwE/tiF27HHTiBk7gTp3AaZ3AW53AeF3AXLuISLuMKruIa7sZ13IMbuIl7cQu/4w@8wEv8iVd4jTd4i3d4jw/4Cx/xCZ/xBV/xN77jH/zAT/wiHARBkISToAiaYAiW4AieEAgXIRISIRMKoRIa4SZ0wkMYhEl4CYvr4BJciktzGS7H5bkC18WVuQpX5epcD9fgmlwv1yLuxIOoiJpoiZ4YiJGYiJlYiJXYiDexEwdxEhdpJx0kQZKkk6RImmRJjhRIFymSEimTCqmRblInPaRBmqSXtMgHWZAl@SQrsiYbsiU7sicH8kWO5ETO5EKu5Ea@yZ38kAd5kl/youyUgyIoknJSFEVTDMVSHMVTAuWiREqiZEqhVEqj3JROeSiDMikvZVF36kEVVEk9qYqqqYbqqJ4aqBc1UhM1Uwu1Uhv1pnbqQx3USX2pi7bTDtpJUzRNMzRLczRPC7SLFmmJlmmFVmmNdtM67aEN2qS9tMW9cx/cgltyn9yKW3MbbsvtuD134L64E3fmLtyVu3Hf3J374R7cL/ei7/SDLuiSftIVXdMN3dId3dMD/aJHeqJneqFXeqN3@kMf9El/6Yvn4BE8kufkUTyax/BYHsfjeQLPxRN5Ek/mKTyVp/F0nodn8Eyel2cxDoZgSMbJUAzNMAzH8IzAuBiRkRiZURiV0Rg3ozMGYzIWc2ceTMGUzJOpmJppmJbpmJ4ZmBczMhMzMwuzMhvzZnbmwxzMyXyZi3fnPXgFr@Q9eRWv5jW8ltfxet7Ae/FG3sSbeQtv5W28N2/nfXgH7@R9eRdrZx0swZKsk6VYmmVYluVYnhVYFyuyEiuzCquyGutmddbDGqzJelmLnz@//bj73z72y9d/f/l8fvl8/evL73/988@/fv/9v5/PT5/xx9e/v/z57csv//h8//4/)**

### Somewhat ungolfed

```
/OR/_not ./

/AL/-//AK/-//AZ/-//AR/-//CA/-//CO/-//CT/-//DE/-//FL/-//GA/-//HI/-//ID/-//IL/-//IN/-//IA/-//KS/-//KY/-//LA/-//ME/-//MD/-//MA/-//MI/-//MN/-//MS/-//MO/-//MT/-//NE/-//NV/-//NH/-//NJ/-//NM/-//NY/-//NC/-//ND/-//OH/-//OK/-//PA/-//RI/-//SC/-//SD/-//TN/-//TX/-//UT/-//VT/-//VA/-//WA/-//WV/-//WI/-//WY/-/

/AA/,//AB/,//AC/,//AD/,//AE/,//AF/,//AG/,//AH/,//AI/,//AJ/,//AM/,//AN/,//AO/,//AP/,//AQ/,//AS/,//AT/,//AU/,//AV/,//AW/,//AX/,//AY/,//BA/,//BB/,//BC/,//BD/,//BE/,//BF/,//BG/,//BH/,//BI/,//BJ/,//BK/,//BL/,//BM/,//BN/,//BO/,//BP/,//BQ/,//BR/,//BS/,//BT/,//BU/,//BV/,//BW/,//BX/,//BY/,//BZ/,//CB/,//CC/,//CD/,//CE/,//CF/,//CG/,//CH/,//CI/,//CJ/,//CK/,//CL/,//CM/,//CN/,//CP/,//CQ/,//CR/,//CS/,//CU/,//CV/,//CW/,//CX/,//CY/,//CZ/,//DA/,//DB/,//DC/,//DD/,//DF/,//DG/,//DH/,//DI/,//DJ/,//DK/,//DL/,//DM/,//DN/,//DO/,//DP/,//DQ/,//DR/,//DS/,//DT/,//DU/,//DV/,//DW/,//DX/,//DY/,//DZ/,//EA/,//EB/,//EC/,//ED/,//EE/,//EF/,//EG/,//EH/,//EI/,//EJ/,//EK/,//EL/,//EM/,//EN/,//EO/,//EP/,//EQ/,//ER/,//ES/,//ET/,//EU/,//EV/,//EW/,//EX/,//EY/,//EZ/,//FA/,//FB/,//FC/,//FD/,//FE/,//FF/,//FG/,//FH/,//FI/,//FJ/,//FK/,//FM/,//FN/,//FO/,//FP/,//FQ/,//FR/,//FS/,//FT/,//FU/,//FV/,//FW/,//FX/,//FY/,//FZ/,//GB/,//GC/,//GD/,//GE/,//GF/,//GG/,//GH/,//GI/,//GJ/,//GK/,//GL/,//GM/,//GN/,//GO/,//GP/,//GQ/,//GR/,//GS/,//GT/,//GU/,//GV/,//GW/,//GX/,//GY/,//GZ/,//HA/,//HB/,//HC/,//HD/,//HE/,//HF/,//HG/,//HH/,//HJ/,//HK/,//HL/,//HM/,//HN/,//HO/,//HP/,//HQ/,//HR/,//HS/,//HT/,//HU/,//HV/,//HW/,//HX/,//HY/,//HZ/,//IB/,//IC/,//IE/,//IF/,//IG/,//IH/,//II/,//IJ/,//IK/,//IM/,//IO/,//IP/,//IQ/,//IR/,//IS/,//IT/,//IU/,//IV/,//IW/,//IX/,//IY/,//IZ/,//JA/,//JB/,//JC/,//JD/,//JE/,//JF/,//JG/,//JH/,//JI/,//JJ/,//JK/,//JL/,//JM/,//JN/,//JO/,//JP/,//JQ/,//JR/,//JS/,//JT/,//JU/,//JV/,//JW/,//JX/,//JY/,//JZ/,//KA/,//KB/,//KC/,//KD/,//KE/,//KF/,//KG/,//KH/,//KI/,//KJ/,//KK/,//KL/,//KM/,//KN/,//KO/,//KP/,//KQ/,//KR/,//KT/,//KU/,//KV/,//KW/,//KX/,//KZ/,//LB/,//LC/,//LD/,//LE/,//LF/,//LG/,//LH/,//LI/,//LJ/,//LK/,//LL/,//LM/,//LN/,//LO/,//LP/,//LQ/,//LR/,//LS/,//LT/,//LU/,//LV/,//LW/,//LX/,//LY/,//LZ/,//MB/,//MC/,//MF/,//MG/,//MH/,//MJ/,//MK/,//ML/,//MM/,//MP/,//MQ/,//MR/,//MU/,//MV/,//MW/,//MX/,//MY/,//MZ/,//NA/,//NB/,//NF/,//NG/,//NI/,//NK/,//NL/,//NN/,//NO/,//NP/,//NQ/,//NR/,//NS/,//NT/,//NU/,//NW/,//NX/,//NZ/,//OA/,//OB/,//OC/,//OD/,//OE/,//OF/,//OG/,//OI/,//OJ/,//OL/,//OM/,//ON/,//OO/,//OP/,//OQ/,//OS/,//OT/,//OU/,//OV/,//OW/,//OX/,//OY/,//OZ/,//PB/,//PC/,//PD/,//PE/,//PF/,//PG/,//PH/,//PI/,//PJ/,//PK/,//PL/,//PM/,//PN/,//PO/,//PP/,//PQ/,//PR/,//PS/,//PT/,//PU/,//PV/,//PW/,//PX/,//PY/,//PZ/,//QA/,//QB/,//QC/,//QD/,//QE/,//QF/,//QG/,//QH/,//QI/,//QJ/,//QK/,//QL/,//QM/,//QN/,//QO/,//QP/,//QQ/,//QR/,//QS/,//QT/,//QU/,//QV/,//QW/,//QX/,//QY/,//QZ/,//RA/,//RB/,//RC/,//RD/,//RE/,//RF/,//RG/,//RH/,//RJ/,//RK/,//RL/,//RM/,//RN/,//RO/,//RP/,//RQ/,//RR/,//RS/,//RT/,//RU/,//RV/,//RW/,//RX/,//RY/,//RZ/,//SA/,//SB/,//SE/,//SF/,//SG/,//SH/,//SI/,//SJ/,//SK/,//SL/,//SM/,//SN/,//SO/,//SP/,//SQ/,//SR/,//SS/,//ST/,//SU/,//SV/,//SW/,//SX/,//SY/,//SZ/,//TA/,//TB/,//TC/,//TD/,//TE/,//TF/,//TG/,//TH/,//TI/,//TJ/,//TK/,//TL/,//TM/,//TO/,//TP/,//TQ/,//TR/,//TS/,//TT/,//TU/,//TV/,//TW/,//TY/,//TZ/,//UA/,//UB/,//UC/,//UD/,//UE/,//UF/,//UG/,//UH/,//UI/,//UJ/,//UK/,//UL/,//UM/,//UN/,//UO/,//UP/,//UQ/,//UR/,//US/,//UU/,//UV/,//UW/,//UX/,//UY/,//UZ/,//VB/,//VC/,//VD/,//VE/,//VF/,//VG/,//VH/,//VI/,//VJ/,//VK/,//VL/,//VM/,//VN/,//VO/,//VP/,//VQ/,//VR/,//VS/,//VU/,//VV/,//VW/,//VX/,//VY/,//VZ/,//WB/,//WC/,//WD/,//WE/,//WF/,//WG/,//WH/,//WJ/,//WK/,//WL/,//WM/,//WN/,//WO/,//WP/,//WQ/,//WR/,//WS/,//WT/,//WU/,//WW/,//WX/,//WZ/,//XA/,//XB/,//XC/,//XD/,//XE/,//XF/,//XG/,//XH/,//XI/,//XJ/,//XK/,//XL/,//XM/,//XN/,//XO/,//XP/,//XQ/,//XR/,//XS/,//XT/,//XU/,//XV/,//XW/,//XX/,//XY/,//XZ/,//YA/,//YB/,//YC/,//YD/,//YE/,//YF/,//YG/,//YH/,//YI/,//YJ/,//YK/,//YL/,//YM/,//YN/,//YO/,//YP/,//YQ/,//YR/,//YS/,//YT/,//YU/,//YV/,//YW/,//YX/,//YY/,//YZ/,//ZA/,//ZB/,//ZC/,//ZD/,//ZE/,//ZF/,//ZG/,//ZH/,//ZI/,//ZJ/,//ZK/,//ZL/,//ZM/,//ZN/,//ZO/,//ZP/,//ZQ/,//ZR/,//ZS/,//ZT/,//ZU/,//ZV/,//ZW/,//ZX/,//ZY/,//ZZ/,/

/-/_./
/_/I am /
/./an engineer/
/,/What is .?/
```

**[TIO, with some examples](https://tio.run/##JddJbhtHAAXQvU6hA9jmEQL1PA/VU3VvBC0E20CiAJHvr4hPmw@JLPZ/9bni@98v779e3z8@bmO4Pb/9@@fxx@3h4fbU3b7fbk@tvGS4Z/okR7neM8vvWThfereq71ln0uv1IL3bLvK8Z@eV3hN65/uvVzyh96ne@V5jr3FwfthlJRvZS08eUumZozOju0yeHzx/cWZxZtW1xntuWvavdP74So2Hzx73lvtOT7dvn9skMpWZzGUhS1nJWjayl4Mc5SRnuchVbnKXh4zyvGfCkDAkDAlDwpAwJAwJQ8KQMCSt7CRPwpPwJDwJTxIkVUKVUCVUCVVClXyprnumVClVSpVSpVQpVUqVUqVUKVVKlVKlVClPypPypDwpSUqSkqQkKUlKklkp48l4Mp6MJCPJSDKSjCQjyUgykowks0/Gk/FkPBlPZp@MKqPKqDKqjCqjyqlyqpwqp8qtlLPlbDlbzpaz5Ww5W86Ws@VsOVvOlrPlbDlbzpaz5Ww5W86WsxVsBVvBVrAVbAVbwVawFWwFW8FWUBVUBVVBVVAVVAVVQVVQFVQFVUFVUBVUJU/JU/KUPCVPyVPylDwlT8lT2qqkKqlKqpKqpCqpSqqSqqQqqUqqkqqkKqkqW1VsFVvFVrFVbBVbxVZRVVQVVUVVUVVUFVVFVVFVVBVVRVVRVVQVVUVVUdU8NU9NUpPUJDVJbaWap@apSWqGmqFmqBlqhpqhZqgZaoaaoWaoGRrLNCQNSWOZhqfhaXganoan4Wl4Gvs0VI19GraGrWFr2Bq2hq1ha9gatoatYWvYWraWrWVr2Vq2lq1la9latpatZWvZWraWrWVr2Vq2lq2laqlaqpaqpWp5OpKOpCPpSDqSjqQj6Ug6ko6kI@lIOpKOpCPpSDqSzkodT8fT8XQ8HU9npY6qp@qpepKepCfpGXqGnqFn6PX2enu9va5eV6@r19Xr6nUNvpFB46Br0DW476Bl0DK44@COg65B16BrcMfBHQe9g8ZB46Br1DXqGt1utPlo81H7qH3UPrrpqH10x5FhZBgZRoZR@6h91D669cgwMoxuPZJMDBPDxDAxTAwTw2TtiWQimawx8Uw8E8/EM/FMPJNNJqqJaqKaqCaqiWqimqhm@8xsM9vMNrPNbDPbzDazzWwz28w2s81sM9vMNrPNbDPbzDazzWwz28w2s81sgS2wBbbAFtgCW2ALbIEqUAWqQBWoAlWgClSBKlAFqkAVqAJVoApUgWqhWqgWkoVkIVlIFistPAvPwrPwLDwLz8Kz8Cw8C8/Cs/AsPAvPwrPwLDwrz8qzWmm10sq2sq1sK9vKtrKtbCvbyrZSrVQr1Uq1Uq1UK9VKtVKtPCvPxrPxbDwbz8az8Ww8G8/Gs/FsPBvPxrPZaqPaqDaqjWqj2ng2no1ns9JGtVHtPDvPzrPz7Dw7z86z8@w8O8/Os/PsPDvPzrPz7Dw7z86z8@w8O8/Os/McPAfPwXPwHDwHz8FzkBwkB8lBcpAcJAfJQXKQHCSH7@vgOUgOkoMh@qYiSSSJJJEkkkSSSBItE3kiT@SJPJEn8kSeyBN5Ik/kiTzRPpEqUkX7RLaT7WQ72U62k@1kO9lOtpPtZDvZTraT7WQ72U62k@1kO9lOtpPtZDvZTraT7WS72C62i@1iu9gutovtYrvYLraL7WK72C62i@1iu9gutovtYrvYLraL7WK72K677fPX6vfb8@ev@9vzrX58@efx868ft5e3x9e3n7/fXl//@/z/2@349fLn8ff744@/Pj8whof06SGeHx//Aw)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>277</strike> <strike>275</strike> 201 bytes

Here's one where I've compressed the list to 70 characters. But the compression is complex enough that my decompression makes the code uncompetitively heavy. Perhaps someone else has a better decompression idea.

[edit:] You could do this in binary compressed data pretty trivially and save another 25% on the list size. You only need 6 bits/char to do upper and lower case letters. And it'd probably be even more wordy to decode.

The list is lowercase first letter, followed by upper case second letters of everything with that first letter. Order doesn't matter; I used one extra lowercase at the end to make the regular expression work this way.

Using the lambda cleverness from above, it's 201 bytes, but is still too fattened by that regex:

```python
lambda s,e=' an engineer':'I am'+' not'*(s=='OR')+e if re.match('.*%s[A-Z]*%s[A-Z]*[a-z]'%(s[0].lower(),s[1]),'aLKZRcAOTdEfLgAhIiDLNAkSYlAmEDAINSOTnEVHJMYCDoHKRpArIsCDtNXuTvTAwAVIYz')else'What is%s?'%e
```

```python
def m(t):
 p='I am'
 e=' an engineer'
 if t=='OR':print(p+' not'+e);return()
 else:
  w='What is'
  if re.match('.*%s[A-Z]*%s[A-Z]*[a-z]'%(t[0].lower(),t[1]),'aLKZRcAOTdEfLgAhIiDLNAkSYlAmEDAINSOTnEVHJMYCDoHKRpArIsCDtNXuTvTAwAVIYz')==None:print(w+e+'?');return()
  print(p+e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBb4JAEIXv/oq5mIGCpu3RZtNshUSqYoLECoQD0UFIZZcsa0n983Rt2qaXN5mXvMn3pv3UlRSPQ920UmlQNByphMbS9mwELcMAigZHQAyhEEDiVAsiZZy6BM0YbiKctaoW2modBCE1OmQ/KdIXJSzbBM8dmUvQM3yrCg11Z7K3sKJpU@hDZeH0btxlfJLmfzMrJtccx5bO7vPpWfakLNvV2UNuu1islml04Jv46JerE6@C2luF/H2bnHnjezwIt5tY@LvF6zqZe3KxjFqugm7u6XB/iT9i3vNdkFzRZiyUgn7Ye4ccfMb/4PDbiuzRUEoFhl1AhusYXVz7Rkx1F@P9bb3JS2IkTTGffb9v@AI)

Comment: [199 bytes](https://tio.run/##PctBb4JAFATge3/Fu5AHiqTt0YQ0WyGRCpggsQLlsJVVSNldsrutqX@eoodevklmMsOvaaV4Hrn/MfaUfzYUtMt8BCqAiXMnGFO4VMzj1BxbG72ZpSuyKOv/rOjiWqNl6@qx9np5Ycp2XF091Y6LNN6U2ZFs8yY8xWfSRl0Qp@RrV/SEhwGJ0t02F@F@/ZYUq0CuN9lAVKRXgUkP3/lPTi5kHxVXdKhoMALKcY4gpMGZrX0ftxk6cwZS4XtLDXTa0i9osbHjg1QGFHs4SQXTIKDCJEcXMAlvTsfJ/HBv7r4WN8sS6yUMqhMGuG2c8Q8).

Comment: nice. One byte at a time, eh?:)

Comment: \$|201 - 199| = 2 \neq 1\$.

Comment: Okay, _two_ bytes at a time. It was a sentiment, not a count, but I'll roll with ya here.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <s>261</s> 254 Bytes

an anonymous vbe immediate window function that takes input as expected type `Variant\String` from cell `[A1]` and outputs my status as an engineer in the given US state to the VBE immediate window.

### Golfed

```vb
e=" an engineer":i="I am":?IIf(UBound(Filter(Split("AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY"),[A1])),IIf([A1]="OR",i+" not"+e,"What is"+e+"?"),i+e)
```

### Ungolfed

```vb
Function AmIAnEngineer(ByVal state As String) As String

    Dim i As String, _
        e As String
        
    Let i = "I am"
    Let e = " an engineer"
    
    Let AmIAnEngineer = _
        IIf(UBound(Filter( _
                Split("AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY"), _
                state)), IIf(state = "OR", i & " not" & e, "What is" & e & "?"), i & e)
End Function

''# Usage:
''#
''#     ?AmIAnEngineer("VA")
''#     I am an engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 186 bytes

```
if.=="OR"then"I am not X"elif inside("MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH RIA UT WVT WIL WY")then"I am X"else"What is X?"end|sub("X";"an engineer")
```

Expanded

```
  if   . =="OR"                                then "I am not X"
  elif inside("@totallyhuman's genius string") then "I am X"
  else                                              "What is X?"
  end
| sub("X";"an engineer")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDRToMwGIVfpenVlhRfwCyGgDqEggEcDOMFZp2rwTIHxJs9u/hx5cWXtD1/T8/p5/cs/UQJP4YGciUCHzIolQjvlXhAf@RsGykRhcA@SoGzuIC9EglrzaxG18uaWc2MRtd4abxS9HQHW3gCDdxNA@BexnlGjowMz3jkeBRoBVqJV1kr8YLPbgG9WsCvYq7Cp0ZvGnkdzp0dV1IJuX59u872eLPZyCyX48k4GYn2S7h@FLU0nT0K6wZ7MCupozTwE5/AQZnqdOfHex5oCJLzAfQndhTyL3ER0pSiwHhZ04s6NKEEXbfk9slJNIgSosn1/9PLs4OR1akdhR1EfSeNO1yH6X0la3krWyeM@7DOmItcz/Nvfx5t74bZ89zUdZ5152lkc2l/vH4a2fwB)

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 195 bytes

```
if.=="OR"then"I am not X" elif test("A[LKRZ]|I[ADLN]|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|W[AIVY]|[GCLPV]A|[CUV]T|CO|DE|FL|HI|KS|KY|OH|OK|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX")then"I am X"else"What is X?"end|sub("X";"an engineer")
```

Expanded

```
  if   . =="OR"          then "I am not X"
  elif test("big regex") then "I am X"
  else                        "What is X?"
  end
| sub("X";"an engineer")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NboMwEIRfxfIpkUxfoIoqBDQ4YBwBAQLiQFWnoaImDaBe9tlLJ6cePu3PzI7283vlbiyYG4EapIJ5LtAgF8wPBHuFvsculIJJH2CWCcAuysBZsBi9gldBV48eXgWPgq6QpZCVQE8KEIIDUAC3iQdwp7HX@EPjhyMyUmRk0DJoObLySrATcooH0MsHyCvhK5FTQa9rTtNt6OcNF4xvm5bW/vK023Gd8vlqLJes@2J2nFnFmRn6C5vNBLPbxFFatyQb14@TlhRqIBOd5S0ljecH4UEV55bKxpWP2uy9@Fi0LjXeqWhz8jT5Ab3GFEqKMorOpEPSEaWSMo8yn/KE8opv/3@ouBkmw8trN7N@YtULN/adpuVtwyv@zDvLjP3orTF3vl3X3/E296OdVsexyzA4vb0tM4Z79@OMy4zhDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 227 bytes

```python
lambda i:['What is an engineer?','I am '+'not '*(i>'OR')+'an engineer'][i in'AL&AK&AZ&AR&CA&CO&CT&DE&FL&GA&HI&ID&IL&IN&IA&KS&KY&LA&M&MD&MA&MI&MN&MS&MO&MT&NE&NV&NH&NJ&NM&NY&NC&ND&OH&OK&OR&PA&RI&SC&SD&TN&TX&UT&VT&VA&WA&WV&WI&WY']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY89T8MwGIR3foWnexPKxoYE6MUpxCS2URLyQengipRaat2qZOHXh7BUrXS606O75Q6/w2Yfbsf1/ee4dbvVlxP@bkHNxg3C/wgXRB@@fej74yPdkBJuJ2hGYT8Iuo78A9mC4hmdzWi58MIH4hycgT/ABSRDWsgKyRzPOV4YqYJKoHIoA8XISmQdcoaGTqCnVNAGuoS20BXMHKaGSWFeYTRMByNhEtgUNoMt8MYoFEqJMkFlULV4r1BPYjSTajQKTUfL8XD0YYjWEUmmOL464f@PM2zbC1xt3VPOJ5@68Q8)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 180 bytes

```javascript
x=>[`What is${e=" an engineer"}?`,`I am${x=="OR"?" not"+e:e}`][+!!/A[LKZR]|CO|DE|FL|[GPVCL]A|[HR]I|I[DLNA]|K[SY]|M[EDAINSOT]|N[EVHJMYCD]|O[HKR]|S[CD]|T[NX]|[UVC]T|W[AVIY]/.exec(x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LdBNb4JAEAbgu79i3HiAQNUe2qTarSFgKxWhEYu1k00gdNElCg0QQ@Ly2yk2nubjeTOHSaNzVMaF@K3usvyHtwlta/qC4fYQVSDKwYVTAlEGPNuLjPOCNLNQD22IToNLTSnx1mRGIMsrovEJb0KGWr8/MtBZfq@ZND1pzeWrI/HtIzAdZkhcrJktbbQc12Byif6OyRXOLcN2fW/DpIvzYPG@2pkWkx4ult0RH6/DBt0vJvEzMNlGbtEI7B0bDXnNY6VWWRsDhfG0l@QFKKLrHx@mIOAZnu67qmkqXHrwj@kN0xumN4RzVEDZoV8VItsPkyI/mYeoMLuvKEKHVJ12oTjPyvzIh8d8ryRKqeKY9SnZkpmmxZMYdCh1uO6v4abXtH8)

Somehow the combination of the previous 2 JS answers.

Comment: Why use `!!reg.exec` not `reg.test`?

Comment: @l4m2 Oh I forgot `.test` method! That helps!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 161 bytes

```python
o=('What is%s?','I am'+' not'*(i=='OR')+"%s")[i in'MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH ORIA UT WVT WIL WY']%' an engineer'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDoIwGEXhV7lpQn4QN@fGNIBSoa1BBNE4MBDpYCHA4tMjwzedM/6WfnCH1XJmCrYO3Ke6bxfY2ZuPtCeJ9kshwQ0L7XzLOZmCgpB5MwteFtaRkjoSuYC6RaVWuhJZg1o8cRUFTjnOAjqVMSKT3WKoBCrebHv5gE6gL9AN9FZMClNIgXuJutrIHHVDb4/QOnTuY13XTbSOk3WLPwTrHw)

Comment: Yeah uh, from looking at others' answers, mine is pretty much exactly the same as a couple others. Not sure if this counts, but I came to this answer independently.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. As an answer to your comment, yes -- you can answer duplicate answers -- we try to give the benefit of the doubt that the answer was not simply copied.
However, your answer does not comply with our [default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) -- either write a function or print to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 145 bytes

I wish I could do stack manipulation in Pyth. *Overly* late to the party...

```
X_1@c"I am not 
I am 
What is?"b._x"ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY"Q" an engineer"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDoIwFAX3nOLlH8DEE2gDKBX6UagU2JBqiLCwGmWhp6@Ni8mb5M3zu0zet8N6eyUJe4d7LIj@FpnJLpjfG7qshg@VlRRQkmNRhK1jzYobkXcwosdRVNgV2AtwJhPEZV4nUClUEgi5bsEp@ADuwOEpM5w1TBOQBUxHJ4J1GN1tduP4Iu9Jt/QD)

### Explanation

````
"ORIA MINCALA MSCTNMNVAKY WAZ PAR FL GA NHID COKSD ME MDE MA MTX NE NJ NY ND MOH UT WVT WIL WY"

The magic string from @BusinessCat's answer

x↑Q

What is the string's index in the above magic string? -1 for nonexistent.

._↑

Find the sign, yielding 1, 0, -1.

c"I am not 
I am 
What is?"b

Split the string into a list of newlines.

@↑ ↑↑

Index the sign into the above splitted list

X_1↑" an engineer"

Insert the string " an engineer" before the last character
```
````