# From Plate to State

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

This is essentially the inverse of [Generate a US License Plate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128705/generate-a-us-license-plate)

**Challenge:** Given a string that matches one of the below license plate formats, output all possible states that match that formatting. In the below table `0` stands for a single digit `0` through `9` inclusive, and `A` stands for a single letter `A` through `Z` inclusive. For the purposes of this challenge, we're ignoring states with complex format rules (like Delaware, which has variable number of digits), and ignoring removal of look-alike letters (e.g., `I` and `1`).

```
AAA 000: AK, IA, MS, MP, VT
0000: AS
AAA0000: AZ, GA, WA
000 AAA: AR, KS, KY, LA, ND, OR
0AAA000: CA
AA-00000: CT
AA-0000: DC
AAA A00: FL
AA 00000: IL
000A,000AA,000AAA,AAA000: IN
0AA0000: MD
AAA 0000,0AA A00,AAA 000: MI
000-AAA: MN
00A-000: NV
000 0000: NH
A00-AAA: NJ
000-AAA,AAA-000: NM
AAA-0000: NY, NC, PA, TX, VA, WI
AAA 0000: OH
000AAA: OK
AAA-000: PR
000-000: RI
AAA 000,000 0AA: SC
A00-00A: TN
A00 0AA: UT
```

Examples:

```
B32 9AG
[UT]

1YUC037
[CA]

285 LOR
[AR, KS, KY, LA, ND, OR] (in any order)

285-LOR
[MN, NM] (in any order)

285LOR
[IN, OK] (in any order)
```

**Rules and Clarifications**

- The input string is guaranteed non-empty, and guaranteed to be of one of the above formats
- Behavior if given a format other than the above is undefined
- Input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963)
- You can print the result to STDOUT or return it as a function result
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>203 202 201</s>  200 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @NahuelFouilleul*

```javascript
s=>'xMiAZGAWaMIOhNvInxMNNmARKSKYLANDOrNMPrAKIAMIMSMPSCVtAsMdxScRiNhUtDcCtxFlxNYNCPATXVAWiInIlINOkNjCaTn'.match(/[A-Z]*./g)[s.replace(/./g,c=>c<'!'?0:1/c?9:6-~(c+1))*3%47%30].toUpperCase().match(/../g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcwxb4JAAIbhvb@CDgawBQRsraZormc0F7yDgGjROFxOFCwC4Yhh6l@nOHRp6PANX57kvdAb5axMikrJ8mPUnKyGW1OxxgnYLcGWYuTE5IayGhNyBZ7t2@EKkLlTEuyWwEYAI@xj14ebCnB8rH3mJSQOqjmDVb1IaxIS6IL15wZsE5ShFBHni1wgXWeieqUViyVtD5Tdoa9qZ3nP1TIqUsoiSWv/M7Om7F18FGeDia6x2XjyqnxL7EmX5b7ZG4565uCgVnlQFFEJKY8k@Tep3msNyzOep5Ga5mfpJIkfpiGMwVKU5Yc/oocBHJijDjHeXoSV43WL8q90g26YQrthBy0c506tND8)

### How?

#### Input conversion

We turn the input string into an integer \$n\$ by applying the following substitutions:

- spaces are replaced with \$0\$
- digits are replaced with \$9\$
- letters are replaced with \$7\$
- hyphens are replaced with \$6\$

As JS code:

```javascript
c < '!' ?        // if c is a space:
  0              //   replace it with 0
:                // else:
  1 / c ?        //   if c is a digit:
    9            //     replace it with 9
  :              //   else:
    6 - ~(c + 1) //     if c is a hyphen, this gives:
                 //       6 - ~('-1') --> 6 - 0 --> 6
                 //     if c is a letter (e.g. 'A'), this gives:
                 //       6 - ~('A1') --> 6 - ~NaN --> 6 - (-1) --> 7
```

#### Hash function

We then apply the following hash function:

$$f(n) = ((3\times n) \bmod 47) \bmod 30$$

This gives a unique ID in \$[1..29]\$. There's actually a collision between `000AA` and `AAA000` which both result in \$24\$, but that's perfectly fine as these plate formats are used in Indiana exclusively.

```
 format     | n        | * 3       | mod 47 | mod 30 | states
------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------------
  'AAA 000' |  7770999 |  23312997 |   10   |   10   | AK,IA,MI,MS,MP,SC,VT
     '0000' |     9999 |     29997 |   11   |   11   | AS
  'AAA0000' |  7779999 |  23339997 |   32   |    2   | AZ,GA,WA
  '000 AAA' |  9990777 |  29972331 |    8   |    8   | AR,KS,KY,LA,ND,OR
  '0AAA000' |  9777999 |  29333997 |   28   |   28   | CA
 'AA-00000' | 77699999 | 233099997 |   19   |   19   | CT
  'AA-0000' |  7769999 |  23309997 |   18   |   18   | DC
  'AAA A00' |  7770799 |  23312397 |   21   |   21   | FL
 'AA 00000' | 77099999 | 231299997 |   25   |   25   | IL
     '000A' |     9997 |     29991 |    5   |    5   | IN
    '000AA' |    99977 |    299931 |   24   |   24   | IN
   '000AAA' |   999777 |   2999331 |   26   |   26   | IN,OK
   'AAA000' |   777999 |   2333997 |   24   |   24   | IN
  '0AA0000' |  9779999 |  29339997 |   12   |   12   | MD
 'AAA 0000' | 77709999 | 233129997 |   33   |    3   | MI,OH
  '0AA A00' |  9770799 |  29312397 |    1   |    1   | MI
  '000-AAA' |  9996777 |  29990331 |    7   |    7   | MN,NM
  '00A-000' |  9976999 |  29930997 |   34   |    4   | NV
 '000 0000' | 99909999 | 299729997 |   46   |   16   | NH
  'A00-AAA' |  7996777 |  23990331 |   27   |   27   | NJ
  'AAA-000' |  7776999 |  23330997 |    9   |    9   | NM,PR
 'AAA-0000' | 77769999 | 233309997 |   23   |   23   | NY,NC,PA,TX,VA,WI
  '000-000' |  9996999 |  29990997 |   15   |   15   | RI
  '000 0AA' |  9990977 |  29972931 |   44   |   14   | SC
  'A00-00A' |  7996997 |  23990991 |   29   |   29   | TN
  'A00 0AA' |  7990977 |  23972931 |   17   |   17   | UT
```

#### State encoding

All state patterns are joined together into a single string, with each pattern ending with a lower case letter. Empty slots are filled with an arbitrary `x`.

```
[ [], [ 'MI' ], [ 'AZ', 'GA', 'WA' ], [ 'MI', 'OH' ], ... ] --> 'xMiAZGAWaMIOh...'
```

We split them back into an array of strings with `match(/[A-Z]*./g)` and pick the correct one according to \$f(n)\$.

Finally, the pattern itself is converted to full upper case and split into groups of 2 characters.

Comment: I love how you always come up with such an elegant mathematical solution to a string-related problem. :)

Comment: D'oh! I'm not having a good day today, am I?!

Comment: Very clever method! The two plate formats that collide are Indiana, not Illinois.

Comment: `[A-Z]*.` instead of `.*?[a-z]` should save one byte

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I've done that mistake before... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 475 bytes

```sql
SELECT STUFF(value,1,8,'')
FROM STRING_SPLIT('000 0000NH|000 055 SC|000 555 AR,KS,KY,LA,ND,OR|0000    AS|000-000 RI|0005    IN|00055   IN|000555  IN,OK|000-555 MN,NM|005-000 NV|055 500 MI|0550000 MD|0555000 CA|500 055 UT|500-005 TN|500-555 NJ|55 00000IL|55-0000 DC|55-00000CT|555 000 AK,IA,MI,MS,MP,SC,VT|555 0000MI,OH|555 500 FL|555000  IN|555-000 NM,PR|5550000 AZ,GA,WA|555-0000NY,NC,PA,TX,VA,WI','|')
,i WHERE v LIKE TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(value,8),5,'[A-Z]'),0,'[0-9]'))
```

Line breaks are for readability only.

Limited to SQL 2017 or higher by use of the `TRIM` function. SQL 2016 (required for `STRING_SPLIT`), is possibly by substituting `RTRIM` at the cost of 1 byte.

Input is taken via pre-existing table \$i\$ with varchar field \$v\$, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341)

I'm basically doing a reverse `LIKE` match: I expand the pattern of each plate to a full [wildcard pattern matching string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like `'[A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'`, then compare to the input value, and return the matching states (which is combined into a single field).

Might be able to save some more space by GZIP'ing the lengthy string; I'll see if that helps...

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 177 bytes

```
§⪪”}∧▶⧴βμÞ∕×peＨ✂d‽n➙ＭR⁶↙↷◨5⁶;πＮM﹪θＷ:¡✂⧴O^(P↷kⅉχＲ⁺≔º↶∨§º⊞Ｂ⎚×p↔Ｌ\`²‖6'⁶⁹‴XüR⦃N4U⊙ＹＦ⁻ＺＭχLＳ⁸ＣX\hγ”;⌕⪪”{⊟“◨⦄»Ｕ>⌕⁻9“]±R▷Ｑ↔θü&$▷l⁹Ｚ⁼¡⁷×À›¶aA*βＺ³δ¡⟲²Y«№⌕TμN»πX·ＳΣ"εl⊙=3✂S?Ｋ”;⭆Ｓ⎇№αιA⎇Σι⁰ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZFda4MwFIbv9yuCVxkcIQwGg3N1SOmaaaIY1667k7ZsgrMiOrZf75Jou4Ykz3u@8sE5fFb94Vw105T3dTtwGlR7PP1w2zX1wCOzQSuRCkgsJHtICcwKsgILhdqA0UgWlZknZAmaLWoXWqEkLA2aF3wtcSVRlqhSn2Y05AWaPRgJOUH5BluCnUJKQBFoBdqCzsFK2JbuKMg2uE6R3uHZpRFGwCKM7oGt6/Z4eaQQgrklMAiiQJoZL/54sYMRFC27B81pRIxmisX2AikcQ4E@n5ZrKJSJC71gF0EL4hsGwW44C7oWiOv37OC68aGrjqu2G4fZ5C5Qnvq26n@5PI@uWxWw2jkjiv4jdvzi3il8LAycpjQr2MPT490Ufzd/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
                 Ｓ              Input string
                ⭆               Map over characters and join
                  ⎇             If
                     ι          Current character
                   №α           Is an uppercase letter
                      A         Then literal string `A`
                       ⎇        Else if
                         ι      Current character
                        Σ       Is non-zero
                          ⁰     Then digit `0`
                           ι    Else original character
        ⌕                       Find index in
          ”...”                 Compressed string of plates
         ⪪     ;                Split on semicolons
§                               Index into
  ”...”                         Compressed string of states
 ⪪     ;                        Split on semicolons
                                Implicitly print
```

[Try all test cases!](https://tio.run/##TZFva4MwEMa/SvCVgxOylrGNe3VLaZtpohjbrSt9IW3ZBGeL2LF9emei/ROMz@9yTy4Jt/3K6@0hL9s2qYuq8VV@9GV1PDX@HTBqZLXb//rmWBaN7@k5GoGUQmggXEFEoCcQp5hKVBq0QjIodf9BHKJeoupSExSEmUb9iosMJwJFhjKyNq0gSVGvQAtICLJ3WBK8SaQQJIGSoAyoBIyAZdaVgniO0wjpA2adjdAD5qHX3XNaVLvzJTnnrJscHRA5pV6DYT0YYhc4ouFvhXobEaNe@RBbQHJlyKn103AMuW38rBbYGWiQ4EYdsBvtgS4b@OV5pula82k7UwDL9nWV13@@OJy6duXAys7hkXfNmNO3bxe5zfUD23a99l7GI/ZMM1v3frUQfPxocfT0wKI4HTC4oqXNpg1@yn8) Link is to verbose version of code. (Slightly different code needed to process multiple cases.)

Unsurprisingly a port of @Arnauld's solution is much shorter at only 121 bytes:

```
§⪪”}∧↨¦↑↧‴q⁰mπi3ＪE⪫³yＳ⪪c)？0≦·ê⊞Þ«ⅉ⁺&±<pAＲιaγ1A↑1L¶⟧/)Vº;Π∧,b✂≦¤ⅉαX⊕|″IνB[w∕¦Ｈ´Gγ§ν⟲^π!⪪¶ςbFü⊟»2”;﹪×³Ｉ⭆Ｓ⎇№αι⁷⎇⁼ι ⁰⎇⁼ι-⁶9⁴⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9NT4QwEL37KxpOJZlNjF@reaemGLdCC6EVXW/NLlEShJUFo78eix68OIfJm/dm5uXtXv2w6307z8XQdCMXo@r29Se3h7YZeQStIJ7pTtCjCJjyDUwFZQBtyGiIklJL6ZYyQSahvITRVJQQKSlB4UBb0gVZSZWDsNAJYCVKBbPBg0MiIR2QZIDZkpFUCHJPVAU/tdioLHTKU5h7SAFnImIRopiY7vdT23PXvNVHfk5M@uPI7RhCvGh/4Ko7TOPvyMO2q4fOD19c9lMI6Yk1gVz/8bfvk2@PvAnf2fL99F9ptUhXAdxE8U8Ru1jHMeY5y0t2dn15Mq8@2m8) Link is to verbose version of code. The second modulo by 30 is implicit in the indexing into the array.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `(-p)`, 165 bytes

Port of @Arnauld's Javascript answer, also upvote him.

```perl
y/0-8/9/;y/- A-Z/607/;$_=('xMiAZGAWaMIOhNvInxMNNmARKSKYLANDOrNMPrAKIAMIMSMPSCVtAsMdxScRiNhUtDcCtxFlxNYNCPATXVAWiInIlINOkNjCaTn'=~/[A-Z]*./g)[$_*3%47%30];s/../\U$& /g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1Bb4IwGIDhu7@iB5ybSfmQ6tAQD98wMw22EBAdOmOMW5SNIQGy1Mt@@qomHt48x7f8rPKB1mew6BBG4J6BEqQreLYccI3t@LGjRIarKS53ggdH@csLJaT8wciP/XSGchJUUoQV@hwFF7EIY2/RYC0@VLyPMnlMmsnea9RrrmQqvRDnbwtcZrzgOZfBt/zydvOiM/6D9fW66ZpweFob2y5r9502szZuDaYJ74nxQOCg9QuzyQinrV6aeBZzWvZwQGZBdJPevdGzGbnW/z@VTXYqak3L/AI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>382</s> 378 bytes

```python
import re;f=lambda p,l='[A-Z]',r=re.sub,f=re.findall:f(l+'{2}',f(r(l,'1',r('[0-9]','0',p))+l+'+','0000AS0001IN00011IN000111INOK111000IN000 011SC000 111ARKSKYLANDOR000-000RI000-111MNNM001-000NV011 100MI0110000MD0111000CA100-001TN100-111NJ11-0000DC111 100FL111 000AKIAMIMSMPSCVT111-000NMPR1110000AZGAWA11 00000IL11-00000CT111 0000MIOH111-0000NYNCPATXVAWI1100 011UT000 0000NH')[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBfb5swEH/vp/DbgUIqk2jqmomHG1lbCjYISNoU5YE2oEWiKXJcadPUz56eTbItSNydf/840//WP99208Nh@9q/Kc1U860Nuvr1eVOz3usCqHD8tAZPBaq53L8/e60Z2u1uU3fdrHW6EfyZfIDXOsrpPPBJ6UDFx9fkAQ5e77oj0ozMiR4sqPiRNPXUqKcxNTpYhBFWhGYgEPO4iFcJynmaEzSmN4/MQJyQUlCAweSSTIwiRMRtEhdzPmSG6FufX0p/8Ml735r4PPQH101iBrNfHKGIRCGyIlyW/qCTIsuHLI5Pt/iAg5bWTY5BPCyPAbRAenf0cbmSYYbl4xIfIuM3N1uU9oqGvQO34mv3sGlappu9dnqPKXd2wVivtjvtVHCDUQIegwyLAtbVvtGOclkQMDO1Dv3ctftXDoxlXa0bNiNLf4b/@NU3L9rg6gzHF/1edwa3YURd2EXg@3TCrvGWiAoWJdBXBtxfLUI@vbJ4iP/wydcvLElzi6NpEBe2rkxN0FQ5N5VE/7vGJ5eQViPO2BMZWTKNiTx8Ag)

Replaces numbers with `0` and letters with `1`, then searches the string for the plate followed by a string of letters. Then it simply returns every non-overlapping pair of letters in that string.

Not the most byte efficient, but a good start (maybe).

I enjoy challenges based on information that can't just be generated.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 176 bytes

```
•1–ºʒÉQ÷¦PαN]lā?¨ìÎ₆™@ΔîÅλEŸʒ»ú<Å§a–½ã…ôkƒ¼½Ü%-ò∊aÍÙ•44374в4вε©gIgQi…'-Q'd'a„ðQ)VIεY®Nèè.V}Pë0].•=#îYn«ÈO4êʒIWj∊bÛˆ_ãZÑ"yŠótм‰иÔN–HδÖc°ìSJ9Ç\}ζÎäǝÑïÒ∞V.÷ζkÚ"¿Õнα£!ÉªB…žä•#sÏ`2ô
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5bSwJRAIR/S0pID0rWQgRFEQXZg7oFhpHUWiFm1IO99CBskaZChpsF3SRcMVMxNW94KTiTBQaH/Q3nj2wnmJeBmW/mKCh5/Xu6zuSMlcnXpDNUEBPRIjknrdo9B1@ncySPEhLsLMLOM/M0hTLCtLs0aA8V0kVnBmHyIv1X@1CZnEM98K2QHnePo2bUWDQu4RJ3nC8Ik1OCVuOiDfLqs/lEP8@bzKJp18QBaVTEMZeNNtykbEceeYsr5ERx3GPh3Vkjyu5DUkTUIaAwVGzr@5zsxcNvZAvqBpKGk8Ez3o@1HpMrWhspO3@0TOu43SEVlNZWpnGxGaJNJJD9eUISb1BYNO2yoEWbAdwbyCdutD6tEnUEMVJY4M8GH8jyaWMQV9sTqOv6omPVbBWswh8)

```
•1–ºʒÉQ÷¦PαN]lā?¨ìÎ₆™@ΔîÅλEŸʒ»ú<Å§a–½ã…ôkƒ¼½Ü%-ò∊aÍÙ•44374в4в
                        push all patterns as base 4 integers (0="-", 1=number, 2=letter, 3=" ")

ε                       for each pattern
  ©                       copy it for later use inside another for for-loop
  gIgQi                   if it has the same length, as input
    …'-Q'd'a„ðQ)V           store ["'-Q", "d", "a", "ðQ"] in Y (05AB1E codes for "equals '-', is positive, is letter and equals ' ')
    Iε                      for each letter of input
      Y®Nèè                   get the 05AB1E code corresponding to the current index of the pattern
      .V                      run it
    }
    P                       check if all positions of that pattern were true
  ë                       else
    0                       push false
]

.•=#îYn«ÈO4êʒIWj∊bÛˆ_ãZÑ"yŠótм‰иÔN–HδÖc°ìSJ9Ç\}ζÎäǝÑïÒ∞V.÷ζkÚ"¿Õнα£!ÉªB…žä•#
                        push list of states matching the pattern

sÏ                      get the entry of that list, that is true in the other list
`2ô                        split into groups of 2 letters and print
```